# SSL Certificate not trusted

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Having an issue with my SSL certificate. Often it seems to work fine, but sometimes the user's browser throws up a warning that it is not trusted.

I know very little about SSL certificates, but here is some information that may or may not be relevant:

- URL: [demo.EnterpriseJazz.com](http://demo.enterprisejazz.com)
- It is a wild card certificate because
  the application uses subdomains (one subdomain per registered organization Example: BobsLawnCare.EnterpriseJazz.com)
- The certificate was cheap for a wild card certificate, I paid around $50 for it if I remember correctly. I believe I got it from a cheap re-seller.
- The server is located in my house on a Verizon FIOS business internet connection. It is not in a data center.

**Seems to work fine with:**

- Safari on my new Macbook Pro
- Chrome on my new Macbook Pro
- Firefox on my windows machine
- Microsoft Edge on my windows machine
- Internet Explorer on my windows machine
- Opera on my windows machine
- Firefox on my Linux machine (CentOS)

**Not trusted with:**

- Chrome on my iPhone 6s
- Safari on my iPhone 6s (screen shots below)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with code or programming.

Comment: I wish I could vote -1000 for posting the gigantic images. Having to page down 10+ times to get through the nonsense is simply inappropriate, and a user of your rep should know better. Shame on you. VTC for posting a non-code related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=demo.enterprisejazz.com) for this site. Apart from a shockingly insecure setup you will notice:

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete.

This means that the client has not enough information to build the trust path to the root certificate and thus can not accept the certificate as trusted.

However a desktop browser will attempt to work around such setup problems by trying to fill in the missing chain certificates, i.e. downloading these from the web or using cached certificates from earlier connections to other clients. But apart from the desktop browsers most other clients will not do it and thus fail.

Comment: Hey Steffen, thanks so much for your response, that's super helpful! Are there any other tools similar that one that you suggest using? I have some Cassandra and Redis database servers that also may have vulnerabilities. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.

After futzing with every nook and cranny of my SSL and http setups, I finally realized "How silly I was to not check the URL first!"

My browser had been connecting to the regular non-trusted site (`http://example.com`) and I had blindly assumed that the broken lock icon meant something was wrong with my cert installation. Duh!

Modern browsers hiding the actual protocol letters behind a pretty icon or user-friendly message that conflates two issues into one - that didn't help.

My suggestion would be to first make sure you're hitting the https version of your site. If not, your first step to the solution is to create an automatic redirect of all http to https.

I hope getting to this post first helps at least 1% of those who had this problem. I'm in that 1%